# AJAX rewrite rule for directories

Tags: ajax, wordpress, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to write a rewrite rule in addition to wordpress's :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I would not like everything to redirect to the main page.  I have multiple sub-directories which need to be redirected too :  http://www.example.com/sub1 and http://www.example.com/sub2.  I'm doing this so my content can be loaded via Ajax.

I thought this would simply be

```
RewriteRule ^/(sub1|sub2)/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1/ [L]
```

Which I placed in the block here:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/(sub1|sub2)/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1/ [L]
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Perhaps with wordpress you must use wp_rewrite_rule?  I figured I could mess with the .htaccess file, get my rule to work, then move it over to functions.

any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

UPDATE:
I've also tried to set the .htacces file back to the wordpress default... and add this code to the functions.php file for my child theme:

```
function AJAX_rewrite_rule() {
add_rewrite_rule(
    '^/(sub1|sub2)/(.*)$',
    'http://www.example.com/$1',
    'top' );
};
add_action( 'init', 'AJAX_rewrite_rule' );
```

Seems to slow the load of everything down, but all files not found are still redirected to the main page, not the subdirectory.

UPDATE #2
I think I was going the wrong direction, as add_rewrite_rule is only to add a rule to the structure already put in place by wordpress.  This all works by interpreting URL's, and changing them to variables for a DB query run by index.

I'm pretty sure I need to use $wp_rewrite->non_wp_rules.   If anyone has more of an idea, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you seem to have ine bad line there:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
# RewriteBase /
# RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f #Means DONT redirect if file exists.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d #Means DONT redirect if directory exists.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sub1/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sub2/
# RewriteRule ^/(sub1|sub2)/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1/ [L]
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

What happens is, every time you add a "RewriteRule" all the "RewriteCond" are applied to that rule, and then you start with a blank slate:

```
RewriteCond A
RewriteCond B
RewriteCond C
RewriteRule Whatever [L] #This applies A, B, and C
RewriteRule Another [L] #This applies no rules
```

Perhaps that will help.

Also, you may try adding your "RewriteRule ^/(sub1|sub2)/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1/ [L]"  right after "RewriteEngine On" if that doesn't work…

Comment: What if you added this (using my first example) right after the second RewriteCond: 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sub1/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sub2/ (I updated the answer)

Comment: From there, you could use a .htaccess in those subdirectories to redirect as you need